# Best way to reduce app size for over 50 megs

Tags: iphone, ios

Two part question.

I have an ipa file that is 26.5mbs and in itunes it says it is exactly that size, but when I install to a device it says that my app is 52.5mbs on the device... why? And does that mean that it exceeds the 50mb download size for non-wifi downloads?

Also Is there a way to remove some of the size like a compress or something? I'm not really sure besides removing images and files how to make it smaller.

Thanks!

Comment: you can, for example, remove the images and download them when the app is started for the first time. Then your .ipa should be much smaller

Comment: Resources such as images and sounds tend to take the lion's share of an application's size. Reducing the number or size of these resources are often the best option. Consider shorter sound which loop, slightly lower quality sounds/images or more re-use. I've found creating both small and retina versions of some images provides almost nothing visually and I have been able to eliminate sets of files this way. I design many of my gradient patterns to be vertical only to allow for unlimited horizontal stretching. This allows me to create 1 pixel wide images in some cases.

Answer (score 3):

If I am not wrong, .ipa is already compressed. That is why your app on Store in 26.5 MBs but after installation, it becomes 52.5 MBs.

Answer (score 2):

I Managed to cut my iPhone app by half just by using this service: http://www.jpegmini.com/
I've uploaded all my jpegs and got a minified version of them (sometime more that 3 times smaller)

I had some animations (which were bunch of "png"s) that asked my graphic designer to flatten into jpg's instead of png's.

at the end i've managed to cut 13 MB from my app just my minifying images.

Answer (score 1):

The size on device will account for any files you created whilst running, uncompressing the bundle, etc. The download limit applies to the size iTunes thinks the file is (i.e. the signed IPA), not the "on device" size.

You can probably get a smaller bundle though, depending on the makeup of your app. If there're a lot of images, you might like to look at http://imageoptim.com/, which is significantly better at crunching PNGs than Xcode's built-in recompression.

Comment: why the increase in size when installed to a device? I'm mostly trying to keep it under 50mbs, and im trying to figure if the ipa is the size that counts or if it is the size on the device